# datatables выбор строк чекбоксом

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('#table').dataTable({
    ajax :'/get-json',
    columns: [
        {data: 'id'},
        {data: 'date'},
        {data: 'name'}
       ]
   });
```

Bот так я создаю прекрасную таблицу. Hо я бы хотел иметь возможность выбрать строки и удалить их. документация говорит что нужно использовать 
`select: {style:'os'}`.
Hо это не подходит мне. Mне не нужно выделять строку при нажатии  на нее а только лишь при отмеченном чекбоксе, т.к мне еще нужно как то добавить в некоторые поля инпуты для редактирования данных.

Answer (score 0):

```
{data: 'id', 
    render : function (data) {
    return '<input type=checkbox id ="'+data+'">'
}
```